# inheritance - exercise

Tags: c#

Alright, so I'm currently learning inheritance, and I've done something, this is the code:

```
class array
{
    int [] arr;
    public array(int[] arr)
    {
        this.arr = arr;
    }
    public int Biggest()
    {
        return arr.Max();
    }
    public int Min()
    {
        return arr.Min();
    }
    public int SumArr()
    {
        return arr.Sum();
    }
}
class array2 : array
{
    public array2(int [] arr):base(arr)
    {
    }
    public double Average()
    {
        return 
    }
}
```

Now, in the derived class I need to get the average of the array and I can't do arr.Average()
The error says: `Error  1   'ConsoleApplication1.array.arr' is inaccessible due to its protection level C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  35  20  ConsoleApplication1`

Anyone can tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks for helpers!

Comment: Others have explained your problem (that arr is private) but no one has bothered asking: why is your first foray into inheritance a wrapper on an integer array? Try to model something that isn't already built into the system; you'll learn a lot more. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

arr is declared as private since you didn't specify a visibility type.  If you change it to protected, then your subclass array2 will be able to access it.

```
protected int [] arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you've made the `arr` array implictly `private` where you have omitted the modifier itself. If you want to provide access to said `field` in your derived classes, you'd need to use an access modifier of `protected`:

```
protected int[] arr;
```

**But** it's not recommend to expose fields this way, as fields should really be for private class state. What you should do, is encapsulate read-only access to that field, via a property:

```
protected int[] Array { 
    get { return this.arr; }
}
```

Which means in your derived class, you can:

```
public double Average()
{
    return this.Array.Average();
}
```

Comment: Like this?:  protected int [] arr;
        protected int[] Array
        {
            get
            {
                return this.arr;
            }
        }

Comment: The whole point is this is just an exercise. You're replacing one "not recommended" practice (not exposing fields directly) with another one. Even though you're "hiding" the field behind a read-only property, you're still returning the array, *which is mutable anyway*.

Comment: Indeed but I want to know those things for the near future, I just wanted to know if this is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't explicitly define an access type for arr, it is implicitly set to private. To be able to access this from the derived class, you should set it to protected.

```
protected int [] arr;
```

There are better ways to do this, e.g. through a property, but that's the general idea.

Comment: @George Duckett Thanks for the correction! Too late for me to be writing anything! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the default access level for a class member is `private`. You haven't specified an access level for `int [] arr`, so it is `private` and hence visible to the other class.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your arr field is private. consider using a write-private read-protected property instead, like this:

```
class array
{
    protected int[] arr {get; private set; }
    public array(int[] arr)
    {
        this.arr = arr;
    }
    public int Biggest()
    {
        return arr.Max();
    }
    public int Min()
    {
        return arr.Min();
    }
    public int SumArr()
    {
        return arr.Sum();
    }
}
class array2 : array
{
     public array2(int [] arr):base(arr)
     {
     }
     public double Average()
     {
        return arr.Average();
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add public or protected to the arr variable:

```
public int [] arr; 
protected int [] arr;
```

If you don't specify otherwise, the compiler will default to making your declarations private.

Comment: use protected instead, so it's only accessible by the subclass. Other classes should use accessors to get to the variable.

Comment: If you only want inheriting classes to have access use protected.